# Tycho build with useJDK=BREE on CloudBees Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, tycho, cloudbees

I created a new maven build on my CloudBees Jenkins which tells the tycho-compiler-plugin to use JRE libraries that match the bundle runtime execution environment ([Release Notes Tycho 0.14](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Tycho/Release_Notes/0.14)). This feature needs a configured toolchain.xml which seems to be missing. My job failed with following log:

> org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.eclipse.tycho:tycho-compiler-plugin:0.16.0-SNAPSHOT:compile (default-compile) on project org.eclipse.scout.commons: useJDK = BREE configured, but no toolchain of type 'jdk' with id 'JavaSE-1.6' found. See http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-using-toolchains.html

Can someone tell me if I am missing something or if this is a feature missing in CloudBees?

Answer (score 0):

Cloudbees build environment indeed don't have a toolchains.xml file set. This is something we can provide, I'll look to get this added for next release.

Comment: Thanks. When is the next release online?